# How to pass a jsp variable to a javascript method as parameters

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
Hello i have this form:<form method="post" action="Toplanti.jsp">
   <input type="hidden" id="dl" name="dl"  value="">
```

And this hs code:

```
<table>
<%for(int i=1;i<od.odasayisi()+1;i++){ %>
    <tr>
    <%for(int j=8;j<21;j++){  %>
        %><td id="bos">
        <input type="button" onclick="oda(<%=i%>)"><%}
```

And this js function

```
    function oda(p){
    document.getElementById('dl').value=p
    var ad=document.getElementById('dl').value
    window.open("Odaici.jsp?a="+ad);
}
```

But this method does not get the parameter p.Is there a way to do this?Thanks

Comment: "But this method does not get the parameter p." — What value do you expect it to get? What does it actually get? What does the JavaScript in the onclick attribute (not the JSP that generates the JavaScript, the final JS you can see in the browser when you view source) look like?

Answer (score 1):

You don't use semicolon

try this:

```
function oda(p){
   document.getElementById('dl').value=p;
   var ad=document.getElementById('dl').value;
   window.open("Odaici.jsp?a="+ad);
}
```